# jQuery wordpress TypeError: $ is not a function $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use jquery to disable checkboxes after two options are selected on a restaurant menu. The options display in a modal. I've tried most if not all recommendations to resolve with no luck.

URL: https://206culinaryservices.com/place-an-order/

base jQuery code:

```
$(":checkbox[name='rms_mod_666[]']").change(function() {
  if ($(":checkbox[name='rms_mod_666[]']:checked").length == 2)
    $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true);
  else
    $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

seems to work fine in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/R7Cwg/1/

but not in my use case.

I've tried wrapping in:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
// insert above jquery code here
});
});
```

this resolves the error but the code still doesn't work as desired.

...

Another unsuccessful attempt:

```
(function($) { $(function(){
var maxCheckboxes = 2;

 $('input[name="rms_mod_666[]"]').change(function () {
     var checkedNum = $('input[name="rms_mod_666[]"]:checked').length;
     var allCheckoxesChecked = $('input[name="rms_mod_666[]"]:checked');
     var allCheckboxes = $("input[name='rms_mod_666[]']");

     //alert(checkedNum + " - " + maxCheckboxes);

     if (checkedNum == maxCheckboxes) {
         $(allCheckboxes).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         $(allCheckoxesChecked).removeAttr('disabled');
//         alert("ooou equals and disable!");
     } else {
         $(allCheckboxes).removeAttr('disabled');
     }

 });
 });
 })(jQuery);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How to reproduce? I only get font errors at your site `MyFontsWebfontsKit.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`

Comment: @mplungjan click on sandwiches, then on the Sandwiches accordion, then on the first option "Variety Sandwich Platter- 24 Half Sandwiches" You'll see the check boxes there.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. No error. I suggest you clear your cache

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for taking a look. I tried clearing my cache but no love. I've updated the issue description to try to clarify.

Comment: That is not how you pass jQuery to the load statement. You need `(function($) { $(function(){ ... });})(jQuery);`

Comment: [tag:wordpress] did you say?  They use $.noconflict, so use `jQuery("...` or wrap correctly (comment above this one)

Comment: I've updated per the above comment now I'm getting a different error message: 
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jquery

```
(function($) { $(function(){
$(":checkbox[name='rms_mod_666[]']").change(function() {
  if ($(":checkbox[name='rms_mod_666[]']:checked").length == 2)
    $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true);
  else
    $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', false);
});
});
})(jquery);
```

Comment: Also tried this. Still no luck: 
`(function($) { $(function(){
$("[name='rms_mod_666[]']").change(function()
  {
    if($(':checked').length == 2)
      {
         $("[name='rms_mod_666[]']").not(':checked').prop('disabled',true);
      }
    if($(':checked').length < 2)
      {
         $("[name='rms_mod_666[]']").not(':checked').prop('disabled',false);
      }
  });
  });
  })(jquery);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap like this ?

```
(function($){
    $(":checkbox[name='rms_mod_666[]']").change(function() {
        if ($(":checkbox[name='rms_mod_666[]']:checked").length == 2) {
        $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
        $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi @Christophe P. thanks! I did and that cleared up the error but it still doesn't work. I think it's because the target of the jquery is loaded after an add-to-cart button is clicked. I tried adding an on-click function but that doesn't work either.